PHP include statement behaviour in function scope
I have a SQL statement for which I have declared a database connection in a class inside of another file. So when I want to use an SQL statement I have to use @include 'connect.php";
Which I use at the landing page
Now comes the problem.
I have another file called "loginpage.php" in which I include multiple functions like so.
<?php
session_start();
@include 'loginscript.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST["form_type"] == "registerform") {
        register(); //from loginscript.php
    }
    elseif ($_POST["form_type"] == "loginform") {
        login(); //from loginscript.php
        
    };
}
?> //Just HTML after that

At the start of both login and register I include "connect.php" again and get no error
function register()
{
    @include 'connect.php';... }

Now I have another page called "forgot-password.php" which is shown on submitting a form on "loginpage.php". Here I call another PHP script using the action tag of a form.
The script's code looks like this:
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
@include 'connect.php';
$reset_email = $_POST["reset_email"];

$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

$token_hash = hash("sha256", $token);

$expiry_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + 60 * 30);

$stmt = $conn->dbh->prepare("UPDATE users 
                                SET reset_token_hash = :token_hash, reset_token_expires_at = :token_expiry_date 
                                WHERE email = :email");
$stmt->execute(["token_hash" => $token_hash, "token_expiry_date" => $expiry_date, "email" => $reset_email]);

But here I get the error that a class inside of "connect.php" is already declared. How come the functions request and login don't produce an error even though they both include "connect.php" again and again, while using it in a separate script by submitting a form causes an error?
As I said I include "connect.php" in my index file right at the start, so by my knowledge both functions register and login should also throw an error since they also include it.
Is there any way I can use the classes of "connect.php" in my script without throwing this error? I really don't understand this behaviour at all.

Classes can't be defined locally, but variables and functions can.

Using include is essentially like substituting the contents of the file in place of the include statement. Scope works the same way as if you'd done that.

So you mean in the functions I don't really redeclare the class globally but only in the function? And in the other script, since it's not local I redeclare the class globally hence the error?

I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood what you said you're doing. Nothing persists between different scripts. The problem happens if you include the file multiple times in the same script. So if you call the function that contains the include statement multiple times, it will try to redeclare the class, and that causes an error.

Don't include the file inside a function. Include it at top-level. If it declares any variables that are needed inside the function (like $conn) pass that as a function argument.

Okay, that makes sense, but I currently use the script that doesn't work through the action tag of another page. What would be the best way to pass my database connection to that? Also just including the file in which my script is located and changing it to a function?

That doesn't matter. It's only redefinition if it's in the same script, not different scripts.

You do the include once in each script, and everything should be fine.

Another thing: Use include_once or require_once. Then if you do include it twice, the second one will be ignored.

Thanks a lot, due to require_once I found out that I mistakenly used require in an include of my file, so it was indeed included twice within the same script. Silly me!

That's what I suspected was happening. This is exactly why the _once variants exist.

I'm not sure if you're aware that @ is a standalone operator to hide error messages.
